# wso2 api manager tutorial issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Followed instructions in wso2am-1.10.0\samples\WikipediaAPI\README.txt

Got the below issue when running the example.

Has anyone encountered this issue ?

thanks

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\humphriesa>C:\wso2am-1.10.0\samples\WikipediaAPI\APIPopulator.bat

C:\Users\humphriesa>set SERVER=http://localhost:9763

C:\Users\humphriesa>curl -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/publisher/site
/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d "action=login&username=admin&password=admin
"
{"error" : false}
C:\Users\humphriesa>curl -X POST -b cookies http://localhost:9763/publisher/site
/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag -d "action=addAPI&name=WikipediaAPI&visibility=pub
lic&version=1.0.0&description=If you want to monitor a MediaWiki installation, o
r create a bot to automatically maintain one, you can use the MediaWiki web serv
ice API. The web service API provides direct, high-level access to the data cont
ained in MediaWiki databases&endpointType=nonsecured&http_checked=http&https_che
cked=https&wsdl=&tags=wikipedia,mediawiki&tier=Silver&thumbUrl=https://upload.wi
kimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png&context=/wikipedia&tiersCollection=Gold&r
esourceCount=0&resourceMethod-0=GET&resourceMethodAuthType-0=Application&resourc
eMethodThrottlingTier-0=Unlimited&uriTemplate-0=/*" -d 'endpoint_config={"produc
tion_endpoints":{"url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php","config":null},"endpo
int_type":"http"}';
{"error" : true, "message" : "timeout"}
C:\Users\humphriesa>curl -X POST -b cookies http://localhost:9763/publisher/site
/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag -d "name=WikipediaAPI&version=1.0.0&pro
vider=admin&status=PUBLISHED&publishToGateway=true&action=updateStatus";
{"error" : true, "message" : "AuthenticateError"}
C:\Users\humphriesa>
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to run this sample on the windows environment.  It is mentioned in beginning of the wso2am-1.10.0\samples\WikipediaAPI\README.txt file. Sorry for that. Reported this in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4871

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I use cygwin on windows for this or need a Linux / Solaris env ?